# How to use multiple dbs in one query?

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

How would one write this piece of code using influxdb-python client?

SELECT column1 INTO 'db2.retention_policy2.measurement2.' FROM 'db1.retention_policy1.measurement1.' WHERE time > '2019-01-01';"

I get the fact that you can create two connections, or even just use one connection to query a db.

One approach could be this:

1. Get the data required from db1
2. Switch db using connection.switch_database("db2")
3. Then what are some way(s) to push the data into db2?

Thank you.

Comment: I have no experience with `influxdb` but can you not simply use the fully-qualified identifier? `db.schmea.table`? If you tried that, why doesn't it work? Do you get an error? If so, what error are you getting? What is the full Traceback?

Comment: I assume something like this could work :
`client.query('SELECT column1 INTO 'db2.retention_policy2.measurement2 FROM "db1.retention_policy1.measurement1" where time > '2019-01-01)`

given :
`client.get_list_database()` returns both :
`[{'name': 'db1'}, {'name': 'db2'}]`

Comment: I just had to give read/write permissions to both databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to give read/write permissions to both databases.